# C++ Get screen resolution on active monitor

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I get screen resolution for monitor where my C++ application currently is?

I can get handle to an active monitor:

```
HMONITOR active_monitor = MonitorFromWindow(GetActiveWindow(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
```

But cannot make anything out of this)

I tried this:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(GetActiveWindow());
if (hdc)
  {
  const int X = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES);
  const int Y = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES);
  ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
  }
```

But it did not work.. How is ot possible to get resolution for active monitor?

Thanks,
Zhenya

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Could you please move your comment into answer?

Comment: Can you clarify why you said the code you showed didn't work?  (Aside from the fact that the ReleaseDC call should use the same HWND argument as the GetDC call.)

Comment: It gave me resolution of my primary monitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try `GetMonitorInfo()` which gives you a `MONITORINFO`.

Details at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx